# Php cant reach XML element

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML-File:

```
<hostgrouplist>
  <recordcount>68</recordcount>
  <hostgroup id="530">
   <instance_id>1</instance_id>
   <hostgroup_name>Track2_Web</hostgroup_name>
    <members>
     <host id="451">
      <host_name>webeu1-2</host_name>
     </host>
     <host id="457">
      <host_name>webeu2-2</host_name>
     </host>
     <host id="463">
      <host_name>webus-2</host_name>
     </host>
    </members>
   </hostgroup>
  </hostgrouplist>
```

I want to list all host names of a hostgroup but I can't pass through the `<member>` tag.

Target is to do this in a loop, but it even didn't work without it.

The last thing I tried is this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ('http://localhost/file.xml');
echo $xml->hostgroup[0]->members->host[0]->host_name;
```

Shouldn't this work? Do you have a solution? Nothing in the related topics helped me, I think it could be a problem with the id in the host tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

foreach ($xml->hostgroup[0]->members->children() as $host) {
    echo $host->host_name.'<br/>';
}
```

Outputs:

```
webeu1-2
webeu2-2
webus-2
```

Comment: Tried this before, Output:

Warning: main(): Node no longer exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\towerswitch\tests\Programm.php on line 12

Comment: The code works for me. There must be something else in your code. Is this your complete code?

Comment: Solution Found. I get the XML from an external Source, if i save it locally first, it works. Thanks!